# If I send my mum an iMessage it goes through to her boyfriends phone?

Tags: iphone, messages

If I send my mum a text message it goes through to her phone number, but today I sent her an iMessage and it went through to her boyfriend do phone instead. Why is this?

Comment: Did she own the phone before he did? There used to be a problem where iMessages followed the phone when it changed owners, but I thought that had been resolved. At least, it's been a long time since I heard about it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that at some point she has signed in to her iCloud account on his iPhone and activated iMessage thus when she receives an iMessage it is also being sent to his iPhone.